# How to move the list item to top when selected in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying the scenario in the ReactJS application like.
created dummy data in App.js itself with name and id, crated another component with List.js where displaying the list items.

### If I selected any of the list item it should be move the item to top like below
before

- A
- B
- C

### after

- B
- A
- C

I created function in List.js file but it not working

```js
//----App.js-------
import "./styles.css";
import List from './List'

const data = [
  {id:1,letter:"A"},
  {id:2,letter:"B"},
  {id:3,letter:"C"},
]
export default function App() {
  
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <List items={data}/>
    </div>
  );
}


//----List.js-------
import React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react'

export default function List({items}){
  console.log(items);
  const [selectedIndex,setSelectedIndex] = useState(0)

  const selectList = (items,ind)=>{
    console.log(ind+1);
    
    const arr = Object.entries(items,ind)
    setSelectedIndex(()=>{
      arr.sort((a,b)=>{
        return a.id===ind+1?-1:b.id===ind+1?1:0
      })
    })
    // console.log(items,ind);
    
  }
  
  return(
    <div>
      <ul>
        {/* {console.log(items)} */}
        {items.map((item,ind)=>{
          return(
            <li key={ind} onClick={()=>selectList(item,ind)}>{item.letter}</li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try this approach. First create items state that will hold the data.

```js
const [items, setItems] = useState(data);
```

Next create a **reorder** function where you pass the clicked **id**.

```js
const reorder = (id) => {
  ...
}
```

Inside the function, we declare the first item that the value will be assigned during filtration later.

And then define a filter function where we get the first item by its **id**, put it inside an array, and assign it to the **firstItem** variable. The filter iteration process should result in **filteredItems** (exclude the clicked item).

Then, clone both **firstItem** and **filteredItems** by using shallow copy, set as **items** by using **setItems** setter.

```js
  const reorder = (id) => {
    let firstItem;
    const filteredItems = items.filter((item) => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        firstItem = [item];
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    });
    setItems([...firstItem, ...filteredItems]);
  };
```

Then, we can render it like this:

```
  <ul>
    {items.map((item) => (
      <li onClick={() => reorder(item.id)}>
        {item.letter}
      </li>
     ))}
   </ul>
```

For example:

[image: Edit silly-grass-gsj34d]

Comment: Thanks a lot @yohanes, this solution is better one. But in the `filteredItems` what is the use of return false and true I'm not understand. Can you please explain

Comment: Filter method callback function is a predicate, to test each element of the array, in this case, the item. Return true to keep the item inside the result array which is `filteredItems`, false otherwise. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/es6-array-filter-method/

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to update the order of the `items`, it's better to have `items` as a state property.
To initialize state with props, `getDerviedStateFromProps` should be used.

```
class List extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {selectedIndex: 0, items: []};
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
        return {items: props.items};
    }

    selectListItem=(id,ind)=> {
        this.setState((state,props)=> {
            let excludingSelected = state.items.filter((itm,i)=> ind != i);
            return {
                items: [state.items[ind]].concat(excludingSelected), 
                selectedIndex: ind
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Prefer `id` as key to index ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)).